# How to install Scipy for pycharm (python 3.6.1) (Windows 10)

Tags: python, scipy, pycharm

I have currently tried multiple methods to download and use Scipy in Pycharm and have had no success yet. These are the methods that have already been tried.

methods tried so far:

1. downloading scipy directly from the project interpreter in Pycharm.
   This did not work and returned the error.

   numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found
2. downloading scipy-0.19.1.tar.gz then tried to load the package useing the 
   'project interpreter' in Pycharm
   This returned the same error as with method 1
3. installing scipy using pip and pip 3 (both as user and admin) using the 
   inputs and getting the outputs shown below.

[image: error shown: 'pip is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file']

after doing some research on this problem i tried changing the path, which 
   did not change the output.

4. using anaconda, was also recommended in multiple places so i downloaded it 
   and installed scipy, THIS WORKED!!!!

[image: shows the program having been installed successfully using anaconda + any additional information that may be useful]

HOWEVER when trying to import scipy in Pycharm i was unable to call on it.
   i have since tried making a virtual environment in the project interpreter 
   but have still not been able to use scipy in pycharm.

I am sure it is obvious by now I have no idea what I am doing, so the questions are...

1. what am i doing wrong with these methods?
2. what can be done to get scipy to work in pycharm?

Thanks in advance for any help offered.

Edit: as I am sure this will be helpful here is the `echo %PATH%` return from console [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add your Python Scripts folder into your PATH if you know how to do it. Then you can use your pip and call install function.

OR you can type following in your command prompt:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Python27\Scripts
pip install scipy
```

if you have another version of python or another name for python folder change "Python27" to your folder name.

To check your current PyCharm interpreter go to File/Settings/Project:'project_name'/Project Interpreter

[image]

And then install your scipy to that Python version.

EDIT 2

1. Previous versions of numpy installed useing pycharm must FIRST be fully 
   uninstalled from site-packages in finder, e.g:

   ```
   C:\Users\Denise\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages
   ```
2. download the correct version of numpy+mkl and scipy for your python version
   from: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/
3. Write this in your command prompt:

   ```
   cd C:\Users\Denise\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts
   pip install C:\Users\Denise\Downloads\numpy-1.13.1+mkl-cp36-cp36m-win32.‌​whl
   pip install C:\Users\Denise\Downloads\scipy-0.19.1-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl
   ```

line 1 is : cd (interpreter path from pycharm with 'python.exe replaced with 'Scripts')

line 2 is : pip install (path of the downloaded numpy+mkl .whl file)

line 3 is : pip install (path of the downloaded scipy .whl file)

Comment: Hi I have just tried this with set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Python34\Scripts   And     set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Python36\Scripts, but this did not work. with regards to changing the python folder name I cant actually find the folder anywhere

Comment: I think your Python version is 34, also make sure which python interpreter is currently on your PyCharm.

Comment: The python version is definitely 3.6.1 but the path is C:\Users\Denise\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe  so i just added this to path - the python.exe +Scripts on the end and tried to install scipy using pip again but still got he same error as before (in example 3)

Comment: Did you check PyCharm interpreter?

Comment: Project interpreter: 3.6.1 C:\Users\Denise\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\py‌​thon.exe

Comment: Brilliant, i am no longer getting the example 3 error, which is a good start. However im now getting  in the cmd window error: numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found

Comment: May be it is because numpy is a prerequisite for scipy. Look at my EDIT 2 again

Comment: Ok just tried this and came up with the same error, so since i already had numpy installed I just uninstalled it and downloaded it again from:    http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/  so that it was the +mkl version and then tried to install scipy once again using pip and got the same error once again

Comment: Can you import numpy in your PyCharm?

Comment: SUCCESS!!!!!! i just installed numpy using :  pip install C:\Users\Denise\Downloads\numpy-1.13.1+mkl-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl   and then tried installing scipy in cmd useing:  pip install C:\Users\Denise\Downloads\scipy-0.19.1-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl     and it worked scipy is no installed in Pycharm ........ Thank you so much for your help wouldn't have got it done without it

Comment: Happy to hear that!

Answer (score 1):

maybe if you have a version of numpy that isn't compiled by **LAPAC**.
Try to download it from: [numpy-1.11.2+mkl-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).Then run the following line:

```
pip install --user numpy-1.11.2+mkl-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl --upgrade
```

NB: You should reinstall SciPys again

Comment: i tried this earlier, but just tried it again and still getting the problem with pip saying " 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"      as well as this i just uninstalled and reinstalled numpy in the project interpreter, however i still got the same result when trying to install scipy

Answer (score 0):

if Python is not in your path :

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Python36\Scripts
```

I insist on the Python36 token, always use your current Python version in your path, then check for older version and remove them to exclude conflicts. Then you'll be able to

```
pip install scipy
```